# How to render the same page from different get request?

Tags: optimization, express, routes, size-reduction

So I'm using express and I was wondering if there was a way to use an array or chain the get request url for my routes. I been searching though documentation and came short. I figured I'd ask here before assuming it's not possible.

Currently this is how I deal with multiple routes that will render the same page.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'Home Page Title'
    });
}); 

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'Home Page Title'
    });
});
app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'Home Page Title'
    });
});
```

As you can see, they all render the same page and title. It greatly increases my file size and makes it unfriendly to look though. Plus if I need to change how the page renders at the express routes level, I have to update multiple times.

Thanks for taking your time to help!

Comment: Can't you write it in a function and use that instead

Comment: So like app.get('/', customFunction(req, res) )  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
var homeFunc = function (req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'Home Page Title'
    });
}
app.get('/', homeFunc);
app.get('/index.html',homeFunc);
app.get('/home', homeFunc);
```

Comment: Yeah I have no clue why I haven't thought about this before. It seems so oblivious now haha, thanks!